# Python Filter List Items Relative to Each Other

Tags: python, list, filter, filtering

Let's say I have a list of tuples:

```
fruits = [('apple','red',23),
          ('apple','green',12),
          ('orange','small',12),
          ('orange','large',1)]
```

How can I quickly and cleanly create a new list with the tuples that have the largest numbers but unique to fruit name. So the ideal result would be:

```
fruits = [('apple','red',23),
          ('orange','small',12)]
```

My current method is this:

```
def check_fruit(fruit, a_list):
    for item in a_list:
        if fruit[0] == item[0] and fruit[2] < item[2]:
            return False
    return True
filtered_list = [fruit for fruit in fruits if check_fruit(fruit, fruits)]
```

Please let me know if there's a better way! Thanks.

Comment: Does the order in which the results appear matter?

Comment: Is your `fruits` list already sorted by fruit?

Comment: Yes, it is already sorted by fruit name, and I'd like the results in the same order ideally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your `fruits` list is already sorted by fruit, use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def fruitfilter(fruits):
    for fruit, group in groupby(fruits, key=itemgetter(0)):
        yield max(group, key=itemgetter(2))

fruits = list(fruitfilter(fruits))
```

Or in short without a generator:

```
[max(group, key=itemgetter(2)) for fruit, group in groupby(fruits, itemgetter(0))]
```

but it could be you could just use the generator without replacing `fruits` wholesale.

Otherwise use `sorted(fruits, key=(itemgetter(0), -itemgetter(2))` and use `groupby` to grab the first item of each group:

```
def fruitfilter(fruits):
    sortedfruits = sorted(fruits, key=(itemgetter(0), -itemgetter(2)))
    for fruit, group in groupby(sortedfruits, key=itemgetter(0)):
        yield next(group)

fruits = list(fruitfilter(fruits))
```

Comment: @ Martjin Pieters -- your second function syntax seems to be slightly incorrect (second line) and you are not using sortedfruits.

Comment: Your second generator is missing a closing parenthesis on the 2nd line. This seems like the best answer, and works! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools as it

fruits = [('apple','red',23),
          ('apple','green',12),
          ('orange','small',12),
          ('orange','large',1)]

uniq_max = [next(v) for k,v in it.groupby(sorted(fruits, key=lambda x:(x[0], -x[2])), key=lambda x:x[0])]
```

returns

```
[('apple', 'red', 23), ('orange', 'small', 12)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = {}
for item in fruits:
    if item[0] not in f or item[2] > f[item[0]][2]:
        f[item[0]] = item

filtered_list = f.values()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     python 3.2
     from itertools import groupby

 1.    [max(v,key=lambda x:x[2])for _,v in groupby(fruits,key=lambda x:x[0])]
```

without itertools groupby function:

```
  2.  [max([(f,c,n) for f,c,n in fruit if f==k],key=lambda x:x[2])
                                        for k in set([i[0] for i in fruit])]


  3.  [max([i for i in fruit if i[0]==v],key=lambda x:x[2]) for v in set(k[0]for k in fruit)]


  4. loop method

   newlist=[]
   newset=set(i[0] for i in fruit)
   for i in newset:
        t=(0,0,0)
        for l in fruit:
           if i==l[0] and l[2]>t[2]:
                    t=l
        d.append(t)
```